# Zurb Foundation - user interaction to dynamically resize a side bar menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize, zurb-foundation

> Forgive me in advance if there is information on this somewhere but I
>   cannot find it!

I'm fighting with myself as to what Zurb Foundation "thing" (column, section, div, widget, etc.) I should use as the container to create a side bar that can be resized by the user.

The following picture shows a handle on the side bar menu for the user to drag to the left or right to shrink or grow the menu.  I don't care whether there is a graphical element for the user to drag.  I'll use whatever Zurb Foundation gives me.

I've been looking on the Zurb Foundation website and for tutorials that might give me a hint how shrink/grow the side bar but the information I found so far isn't helpful.

**What Zurb "thing" should I use / learn to do this?**

[image]

Comment: `Is it possible to enable user interaction to resize a page section?` **yes**, many website do this.  There are also many frameworks that do this or you can do it yourself.  Asking for recommended frameworks is off-topic (questions are closed) for SO.  You may want to rework your question.

Comment: OK.  Give me a little time to rework my question.  Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at http://layout.jquery-dev.com/

Comment: @charlietfl - Thanks for the pointer.  Just letting you know in case I have to remove this question if I can't rework it for SO standards.